# Detect binding property changed within a user control

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, user-controls, propertychanged

I am working on a Windows Store app in which I have a user control as a data template inside flipview.

**User Control: (ImagePage.xaml)**

```
    <UserControl
    x:Name="userControl"
    x:Class="MWC_online.Classes.ImagePage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MWC_online.Classes"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="768"
    d:DesignWidth="1366">

    <Grid Background="#FFF0F0F0" Margin="4,0">
     ...
        <Image Source="{Binding Img}"  Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="984,83,0,0" Width="325">
            <Grid Background="{Binding Colour}">
                <TextBlock Margin="30,30,30,15" Text="{Binding TextContent1}" FontWeight="Light" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FF00ABE8" FontSize="29" />
            </Grid>
            <Grid Background="{Binding Colour}">
                <TextBlock Margin="30,10,30,30" Text="{Binding TextContent2}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="#FF606060" FontSize="17" />
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**User Control Class: (ImagePage.xaml.cs)**

```
private static void OnTitleChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e){
    StackPanel stackPanel = (StackPanel)d;
    stackPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}

public string TextContent1
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(TextContent1Property); }
    set { SetValue(TextContent1Property, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextContent1Property =
    DependencyProperty.Register("TextContent1", typeof(string), typeof(ImagePage), new PropertyMetadata("", new PropertyChangedCallback(OnTextContent1Changed)));

private static void OnTextContent1Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // what I want to do is if TextContent1 or TextContent2 has no value
    // turn the stackpanel visibility to collapsed
    StackPanel stackPanel = (StackPanel)d;
    stackPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Everything is working fine EXCEPT the OnTextContent1Changed is not firing! so I dont know if this is the right way of doing things but basically I just want to switch an UI element within the user control ON or OFF depending on the data binding that is being fed into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TextBlock` doesn't have a DataContext to find the `DependencyProperty` on. If you give your `Grid` a name in  ImagePage.xaml:

```
    <Grid Background="#FFF0F0F0" Margin="4,0" x:Name="MyGrid">
```

Then you can set its DataContext in the `ImagePage` constructor in ImagePage.xaml.cs:

```
    public ImagePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MyGrid.DataContext = this;
    }
```

Which tells the `Grid` (and its decendents) to look for Dependency Properties on the `ImagePage` class. With this, the Dependency Property should get bound correctly. Another problem, though, is that you're telling the `DependencyProperty` that it is on an `ImagePage` with `typeof(ImagePage)`, but then casting it to a StackPanel, which will fail every time:

```
    StackPanel stackPanel = (StackPanel)d; // Throws System.InvalidCastException
```

You could fix this by giving a name to the StackPanel and referencing it directly in your .cs file.

Comment: Thanks @Thanatos, sorry but perhaps I wasn't clear with the problem that I have, I can address the UI element fine,(my bad that I didn't show my entire ImagePage class, I actually have my DataContext declared there) but what the problem I got is 'OnTextContent1Changed' is never called when the page is rendered and the binding data was fed in. I had a Debug.WriteLine in my 'OnTextContent1Changed' method but it was never called.

Comment: Do you set up your DataContext before or after you feed in the binding data? And if you were to make changes to the property at some point after the page is rendered, is 'OnTextContent1Changed' called? I would also try putting breakpoints or Debug statements in the get/set blocks of TextContent1 and make sure they're correctly triggering.

Comment: Thanks @Thanatos, at the end I just changed my structure slightly by checking if the values at the named textblocks are empty or not on the onLoaded, it was a easy fix that I couldnt think of before, I guess I was too hung up on the idea of the binding of the textblocks.